# slick slider vertical centre issue .?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

```js
  $('.wrapper').slick({

            centerMode: true,
            infinite: true,
            vertical: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            variableHeight: false,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            centerPadding: '0px',
            pauseOnHover: false,
            arrows: false,
            speed: 1000,
            dots: true,
            autoplay: true,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1400,
                    settings: {
                        arrows: false,
                        centerMode: true,
                        centerPadding: '0px',
                        slidesToShow: 3
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

```css
   * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
        }

        .slider-wrapper {
        
            height: 100vh;
            position: relative;
  
            width: 25vw;
            background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
        }

        .slides {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        .slick-center {
            background-color: gold !important;
        }

        .slick-active {
            background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);
        }

        .wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 90%;
            background-color: rgb(126, 126, 126);

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>
            <div class="slides">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur
                nobis
                sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto,
                ipsum
                corporis!</div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have made a vertical carousel using slick plugin. when the no. of active slides are less than 5 I have no problem. The problem is when I make no. of active slides greater than 4 it is offset to top hiding some active slides on the top..

I have attached the screenshot..

[image: with 5 active slides]

the same carousel works well when I changed to horizontal

[image: Horizontal carousel]

So I need all of the 5 slides in the centre in vertical carousel.

Comment: You should be using modern layout algorithms like flexbox and grid

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using modern CSS grid layout:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(29 29 29);
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.slides {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 25vw;
  background-color: rgb(126 126 126);
}

.slide {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.slick-center {
  background-color: gold !important;
}

.slick-active {
  background-color: rgb(0 191 255);
}
```

```html
<main class="slides">
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
  <article class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dicta quia aspernatur nobis sapiente optio in accusantium harum eligendi iste alias error nostrum eum voluptas a laudantium iusto, ipsum corporis!
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: I tried both grid and flex for the parent but the results are same..